# firebase connection with 2 servers

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on project which has 2 servers (Php and node.js)
I am reading and writing data through firebase from both servers.

Is it possible to connect firebase database with 2 servers?

Comment: Yeah, that should work fine. From Firebase's perspective there is no difference between servers and clients, they're all just connections. Are you having problems?

Comment: yes facing problems with 2 servers... when i am using my 2nd apache server.. getting error "token is not valid".. even when i am using same token on both servers... on node.js server ... that token is valid but on apache... it says token is not valid..

Comment: Could you be passing the token in some way that mangles it? It's hard to be more helpful without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)